# Como adicionar botão à página de edição de um produto?

Tags: php, magento

Como faço para adicionar um botão à barra "Descrição" no página de edição de produto?
O botão deve ficar apenas na `tab` Descrição, onde tem a descrição do produto.

Eu preciso saber como definir a rota e como montar o Block para que eu insira um botão nele e o mesmo apareça na pagina de edição de produtos, em *adminhtml calatog product tab*.

Comment: Você precisa dar mais informações, mostrar o código que você esta usando e mostrar a parte onde você tem problema para que alguem possa te ajudar. Existem milhares de formas de se fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Faltam muitas informações...seja mais específico...vc esta utilizando allguma linguage de programação? o conteúdo é gerado dinamicamente? poste um exemplo de código...

Comment: Eu preciso saber, como define a rota e como monto o Block para que eu insira um botão nele e o mesmo apareça na pagina de edição de produtos em adminhtml calatog product tab

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é você fazer isso através de um módulo, mas isso traz muitos detalhes que não são o foco no momento.

Repare que o Bloco que você está tentando alterar faz parte do core e está em:
**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php**

Lá no construtor é executado: **$this->setTemplate('catalog/product/edit.phtml');**

Eu creio que é essa a view que você quer manipular.

Aí para a ação do botão, você iria direcionar para um controller do seu módulo, onde o prefixo estaria configurado no config.xml dele. Para maiores detalhes, veja os fontes de módulos Magento que estão no GitHub.

Vou indicar 2 que eu tive algum contato, onde no primeiro eu coloquei um botão de estorno na página administrativa de detalhes do pedido:

- [Akatus Magento](https://github.com/Akatus/Akatus-Magento)
- [OSC Simplificado](https://github.com/diegosouza/one_step_checkout_simplificado)